# Is the Fourier transform bounded from $L^\infty$ to $L^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, young-inequality

I have seen how to extend the Fourier transform as an operator from $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ to $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ with $1 \leq p < \infty$ using Schwartz's class functions and tempered distributions. So I defined the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution $T$ in $\mathcal{S}'$ as the tempered distribution $\widehat{T}$ such that $\widehat{T}(f)=T(\widehat{f})$ for every $f \in \mathcal{S}$. This way, using the density of Schwartz's functions in $L^p$ spaces, we can extend the Fourier transform. Now, since Schwartz's function shouldn't be dense in $L^\infty$, what do I do?

The only thing coming to my mind would be, given $f \in L^\infty$, introducing   a dumping function $e^{-\epsilon |x|}$. This way the Fourier transform of $e^{-\epsilon |x|} f$ should be well defined and there should be some kind of convergence.

This question arises because I'd need to use Young's inequality combined with Fourier transform, and it would be really nice to have something like $||\widehat{f}||_\infty \lesssim ||f||_\infty$

Comment: I do not quite follow. If you take a function in $L^\infty$, then its fourier transform will in general not be a function. For example the function constant equal to 1 has the delta distribution as its fourier transform. What would be the $L^\infty$ norm of the delta distribution?

Comment: This seems difficult for nonzero constant functions, whose Fourier transforms aren't even functions.  Also, the Fourier transform of a wide (large standard deviation small amplitude) Gaussian distribution is a tall (small standard deviation, large amplitude) Gaussian distribution.  So we can make any ratio of $L^\infty$ norms you like just from Gaussians (and in the limit, recover a variant of the initial observation about constant functions).

Comment: Also in general the fourier transform will not be bounded from $L^p$ to $L^p$ for other $p$'s. Take $p=1$ and assume the fourier transform was bounded from $L^1$ to $L^1$. Then we would get $$f \in L^1 \Rightarrow \hat{f}\in L^1 \Rightarrow f\in L^\infty$$ In particular we get that $L^1 \subseteq L^\infty$...

Comment: The constant function is a perfect example of why we don't have this result. The $L^{\infty}$ norm of a dirac delta is infinity.

Comment: Yeah I knew that the Fourier transform of a constant is the dirac delta function (or something involving it, I don’t remember). I hoped there was some way to view at it in a way that made things work, but I guess it’s simply false